# Apple Push Notifications don't work on virtual machine

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to send web push notification to Safari, my js code and backend are working correctly, because on a real machine it works. But when I run a virtual machine for testing, it does not work. After I submit permission to send notifications, nothing happens, no permission appears for the site and no reverce hook send to my backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm found solution for vmware. In the configuration .vmx file, need add something like this:

```
smbios.reflectHost = "TRUE"
serialNumber = "RM125589AGW"
board-id = "MAC-F22598C8"
```